# Can SiteMinder inspect cookies and allow/deny access

Tags: siteminder

Is it possible for SiteMinder to inspect a cookie (not the SM_) set by my application, for a value and if it matches a particular value, allow access to a resource?

For example, if my application sets a cookie back to the client with FOO="kjfkjafbf3nd" is there a way on subsequent requests (with that cookie submitted back to the server) for SiteMinder to see it and do something with it, like compare it against a value, or part of the resource URI, etc and perform an action (allow or deny access)?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that is possible, in any case this does not seem like a good idea. Since SiteMinder is the first line of protection it should not need to depend on the applications behind it for decisions.

If your application has some authorisation logic and you would like to use that through SiteMinder the correct way would be to use SiteMinder authorisation. You could look at using a different Az directory or use the ActiveExpressions/Active Rules etc.

Comment: Sure, we are using SM exclusively for the authentication and the user is logged in. Just trying to restrict them to certain (dynamic) URL patterns. Just trying to see what pieces of information SM has access to for authorization of certain resources. We do use an LDAP for AuthN but this other piece of information is not present in LDAP/DB for this AuthZ of a resource. I like the idea of Active Expressions, they seem powerful and will look into them. Maybe they can see the requests cookies in the Context passed into them and can make authorization decisions based on that. Thanks.